# SQL Query Updating an already exisiting Entry, if not then make a new entry

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, insert-update

Currently I'm working on updating an already exisiting table on my company's db. The connection works fine, my query though gives me some headache.

What I want to do: logging with 2 tables (Job-Table and Step-Table)

therefore I created a custom powershell object with all the neccessary info which I can pass around.
When I start the logging I create a new entry in the Job-Table where one column is empty/null (Endtime of logging: Columnname: Stop). 
Once I have logged through my script I want to add the endtime (to a then already existing entry in Job-Table).

I know there a different ways to check whether you are at the start or end of a logging-job but I want to do it with a Sql Query, so I came up with this SQL-Insert statement:

```
Begin 
    IF NOT EXISTS(Select * FROM job.table
                    WHERE JobId = @JobId)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO logg.Job (Module,JobId,ScriptId,Filepath,Start,Status,Stop,Infotext)
                Values(@Module,@JobId,@ScriptId,@Filepath,@Start,@Status,@Stop,@Infotext)
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO logg.Job(Stop)
                VALUES (@Stop)
                    WHERE( JobId = @JobId)
        END
END
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing some ';' but all my try & error haven't brought me to a solution...

Basically I want to check whether there is an entry in the job.table, with my current Job-ID.
If not, I'm starting a new logg-job and want to insert all the values there are. If there is an entry with Job-ID i can be certain (my code, my way) I want to stop the logging job and therefore just need to update the value of 'Stop' (endtime).

If I use simpler queries like:

```
INSERT INTO job.Table (Module,JobId,ScriptId,Filepath,Start,Status,Stop,Infotext)
    Values(@Module,@JobId,@ScriptId,@Filepath,@Start,@Status,@Stop,@Infotext)
```

I get my values as wanted on the DB, so the connection and data-type errors have already been eliminated.

Where are my Syntax errors? According to my IDE "near WHERE"...

Comment: What database do you use ?

Comment: My company uses Microsoft SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will update this answer with things as I find them.

**1.**

From the chat with OP I have find out that the `job.table` is actually a table name. So this is a first syntax problem.

It should be

```
Select * FROM "job.table"
WHERE JobId = @JobId
```

and not:

```
Select * FROM "job.table"
WHERE JobId = @JobId
```

**2.**

This is not good:

```
INSERT INTO "job.table"(Stop)
VALUES (@Stop)
WHERE( JobId = @JobId)
```

You can do :

```
INSERT INTO "job.table"(Stop)
VALUES (@Stop)
```

or you can use insert into select but you have to describe to me what you want to select.

**3.**

Finaly this should be your code:

```
Begin 
    IF NOT EXISTS(Select * FROM "job.table"
                    WHERE JobId = @JobId)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO logg.Job (Module,JobId,ScriptId,Filepath,Start,Status,Stop,Infotext)
                Values(@Module,@JobId,@ScriptId,@Filepath,@Start,@Status,@Stop,@Infotext)
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN      
            INSERT INTO "job.table"(Stop)
            values  @Stop
        END
END;
```

Comment: I dont' want anything from the DB, I want to write stuff on it and later, when done writing, update my initialize-entry with the endtime.
If there is an entry in the table with the correct ID i just want to add one Value to one specific column. So in the last step a want to select the column "Stop" in my job.table and give a value.

Comment: Hi @TheT please keep it simple. What is job.table ? A table ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, its just a naming convention in our company...
 job.table is a Table named Job on our DB

Comment: Ok, then this is not the way you do it. I will add that as a first mistake

Comment: @TheT please check my answer

Comment: I would if could... 'Job.table' is the name of the table and it was made clear to me the naming convention stands as it is

Comment: Ok @Thet then this statement you made in your previous comment: "job.table is a Table named Job on our DB" is not true. Please be more accurate ok?

Comment: I'm sorry, bloody newby here. But thanks it works now! All i changed within your 3 point was the table name. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition looks weird to me (mb thats just me) and if i count properly im missing some ")"

you might want to try this

```
 IF !EXISTS(Select * FROM job.table WHERE( JobId = @JobId))
```

Comment: following your answer I have syntax error near '!', btw i'm using MS SQL... When adding the ')' does not make any difference.